# Normal map applied as diffuse textures looks wrong

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, normal-mapping

Diffuse textures works fine, but I am having problem with normal maps, so I thought I'd tried to apply the normal maps as the diffuse map in my fragment shader so I could see everything is OK.

I comment-out my normal map code and just set the diffuse map to the normal map and I get this:

http://postimg.org/image/j9gudjl7r/

Looks like a smurf!

This is the actual normal map of the main body:

http://postimg.org/image/sbkyr6fg9/

Here is my fragment shader, notice I commented out normal map code so I could debug the normal map as a diffuse texture

```
"#version 330                                                                                                       \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
layout(std140) uniform;                                                                                             \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
const int MAX_LIGHTS = 8;                                                                                           \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
struct Light                                                                                                        \n \
{                                                                                                                   \n \
    vec4  mLightColor;                                                                                              \n \
    vec4  mLightPosition;                                                                                           \n \
    vec4  mLightDirection;                                                                                          \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
    int   mLightType;                                                                                               \n \
    float mLightIntensity;                                                                                          \n \
    float mLightRadius;                                                                                             \n \
    float mMaxDistance;                                                                                             \n \
};                                                                                                                  \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
uniform UnifLighting                                                                                                \n \
{                                                                                                                   \n \
    vec4  mGamma;                                                                                                   \n \
    vec3  mViewDirection;                                                                                           \n \
    int   mNumLights;                                                                                               \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
    Light mLights[MAX_LIGHTS];                                                                                      \n \
} Lighting;                                                                                                         \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
uniform UnifMaterial                                                                                                \n \
{                                                                                                                   \n \
    vec4  mDiffuseColor;                                                                                            \n \
    vec4  mAmbientColor;                                                                                            \n \
    vec4  mSpecularColor;                                                                                           \n \
    vec4  mEmissiveColor;                                                                                           \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
    bool  mHasDiffuseTexture;                                                                                       \n \
    bool  mHasNormalTexture;                                                                                        \n \
    bool  mLightingEnabled;                                                                                         \n \
    float mSpecularShininess;                                                                                       \n \
} Material;                                                                                                         \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
uniform sampler2D unifDiffuseTexture;                                                                               \n \
uniform sampler2D unifNormalTexture;                                                                                \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
in vec3 frag_position;                                                                                              \n \
in vec3 frag_normal;                                                                                                \n \
in vec2 frag_texcoord;                                                                                              \n \
in vec3 frag_tangent;                                                                                               \n \
in vec3 frag_bitangent;                                                                                             \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
out vec4 finalColor;                                                                                      "  
                                                                                                          "         \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
void CalcGaussianSpecular(in vec3 dirToLight, in vec3 normal, out float gaussianTerm)                                               \n \
{                                                                                                                   \n \
    vec3 viewDirection = normalize(Lighting.mViewDirection);                                                        \n \
    vec3 halfAngle     = normalize(dirToLight + viewDirection);                                                     \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
    float angleNormalHalf = acos(dot(halfAngle, normalize(normal)));                                           \n \
    float exponent        = angleNormalHalf / Material.mSpecularShininess;                                          \n \
    exponent              = -(exponent * exponent);                                                                 \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
    gaussianTerm = exp(exponent);                                                                                   \n \
}                                                                                                                   \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
vec4 CalculateLighting(in Light light, in vec4 diffuseTexture, in vec3 normal)                                                      \n \
{                                                                                                                   \n \
    if (light.mLightType == 1)          // point light                                                              \n \
    {                                                                                                               \n \
        vec3 positionDiff = light.mLightPosition.xyz - frag_position;                                                   \n \
        float dist        = max(length(positionDiff) - light.mLightRadius, 0);                                          \n \
                                                                                                                        \n \
        float attenuation = 1 / ((dist/light.mLightRadius + 1) * (dist/light.mLightRadius + 1));                        \n \
        attenuation       = max((attenuation - light.mMaxDistance) / (1 - light.mMaxDistance), 0);                      \n \
                                                                                                                        \n \
        vec3 dirToLight   = normalize(positionDiff);                                                                    \n \
        float angleNormal = clamp(dot(normalize(normal), dirToLight), 0, 1);                                       \n \
                                                                                                                        \n \
        float gaussianTerm = 0.0;                                                                                                         \n \
        if (angleNormal > 0.0)                                                                                                            \n \
            CalcGaussianSpecular(dirToLight, normal, gaussianTerm);                                                                               \n \
                                                                                                                                            \n \
        return diffuseTexture * (attenuation * angleNormal  * Material.mDiffuseColor  * light.mLightIntensity * light.mLightColor) +      \n \
                                (attenuation * gaussianTerm * Material.mSpecularColor * light.mLightIntensity * light.mLightColor);       \n \
    }                                                                                                                                     \n \
    else if (light.mLightType == 2)     // directional light                                                                              \n \
    {                                                                                                                                     \n \
        vec3 dirToLight   = normalize(light.mLightDirection.xyz);                                                                         \n \
        float angleNormal = clamp(dot(normalize(normal), dirToLight), 0, 1);                                                         \n \
                                                                                                                        \n \
        float gaussianTerm = 0.0;                                                                                       \n \
        if (angleNormal > 0.0)                                                                                          \n \
            CalcGaussianSpecular(dirToLight, normal, gaussianTerm);                                                             \n \
                                                                                                                        \n \
        return diffuseTexture * (angleNormal  * Material.mDiffuseColor  * light.mLightIntensity * light.mLightColor) +  \n \
                                (gaussianTerm * Material.mSpecularColor * light.mLightIntensity * light.mLightColor);   \n \
    }                                                                                                                   \n \
    else if (light.mLightType == 4)     // ambient light                                                            \n \
        return diffuseTexture * Material.mAmbientColor * light.mLightIntensity * light.mLightColor;                 \n \
    else                                                                                                            \n \
        return vec4(0.0);                                                                                           \n \
}                                                                                                                   \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
void main()                                                                                                         \n \
{                                                                                                                   \n \
    vec4 diffuseTexture = vec4(1.0);                                                                                \n \
    if (Material.mHasDiffuseTexture)                                                                                \n \
        diffuseTexture = texture(unifDiffuseTexture, frag_texcoord);                                                \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
    vec3 normal = frag_normal;                                                                                        \n \
    if (Material.mHasNormalTexture)                                                                                 \n \
    {                                                                                                               \n \
        diffuseTexture = vec4(normalize(texture(unifNormalTexture, frag_texcoord).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0), 1.0);  \n \
       // vec3 normalTangentSpace  = normalize(texture(unifNormalTexture, frag_texcoord).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0);            \n \
        //mat3 tangentToWorldSpace = mat3(normalize(frag_tangent), normalize(frag_bitangent), normalize(frag_normal)); \n \
                                                                                                                        \n \
       // normal = tangentToWorldSpace * normalTangentSpace;                                                              \n \
    }                                                                                                                   \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
    if (Material.mLightingEnabled)                                                                                  \n \
    {                                                                                                               \n \
        vec4 accumLighting = vec4(0.0);                                                                             \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
        for (int lightIndex = 0; lightIndex < Lighting.mNumLights; lightIndex++)                                    \n \
            accumLighting += Material.mEmissiveColor * diffuseTexture +                                             \n \
                                CalculateLighting(Lighting.mLights[lightIndex], diffuseTexture, normal);                       \n \
                                                                                                                    \n \
        finalColor = pow(accumLighting, Lighting.mGamma);                                                           \n \
    }                                                                                                               \n \
    else {                                                                                                          \n \
        finalColor = pow(diffuseTexture, Lighting.mGamma);                                                          \n \
    }                                                                                                               \n \
}                                                                                                                   \n";
```

Here is my wrapper around a texture

```
OpenGLTexture::OpenGLTexture(const std::vector<uint8_t>& textureData, uint32_t textureWidth, uint32_t textureHeight, TextureFormat textureFormat, TextureType textureType, Logger& logger) : mLogger(logger), mTextureID(gNextTextureID++), mTextureType(textureType)
{
    glGenTextures(1, &mTexture);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);

    GLint glTextureFormat = (textureFormat == TextureFormat::TEXTURE_FORMAT_RGB ? GL_RGB : textureFormat == TextureFormat::TEXTURE_FORMAT_RGBA ? GL_RGBA : GL_RED);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, glTextureFormat, textureWidth, textureHeight, 0, glTextureFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &textureData[0]);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);

    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);
}

OpenGLTexture::~OpenGLTexture()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &mTexture);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);
}
```

And here is the sampler I create which is shared between Diffuse and normal textures

```
    // texture sampler setup
    glGenSamplers(1, &mTextureSampler);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);
    glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);
    glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);
    glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);
    glSamplerParameteri(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);
    glSamplerParameterf(mTextureSampler, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, mCurrentAnisotropy);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);

    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(mDefaultProgram.GetHandle(), "unifDiffuseTexture"), OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_DIFFUSE);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(mDefaultProgram.GetHandle(), "unifNormalTexture"), OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_NORMAL);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);
    glBindSampler(OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_DIFFUSE, mTextureSampler);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);
    glBindSampler(OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_NORMAL, mTextureSampler);
    CHECK_GL_ERROR(mLogger);

    SetAnisotropicFiltering(mCurrentAnisotropy);
```

The diffuse textures looks like they should, but the normal looks so wierd. Why is this?

Comment: Do you want an algorithm like bump mapping?

Comment: Why you use glDeleteBuffers when deleting texture? Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
diffuseTexture=vec4(normalize(texture(unifNormalTexture, frag_texcoord).xyz * 2.0-1.0), 1.0);
```

Should be

```
  diffuseTexture=vec4(normalize(texture(unifNormalTexture, frag_texcoord).xyz ), 1.0);
```

The reason is before normals are encoded into Normal maps their values could be in the range from -1.0 to 1.0, this doesn't really works with normal R8B8G8A8 images as they cannot store negative numbers. In order to make the image able to store normal numbers we do **Scale and Bias by multiplying by 0.5 and adding 1.0**. This will effectively map the normals' values:

- [-1, 0] => [0.0, 0.5] and
- [0, 1] => [0.5,  1]

Now inorder to get the original values you need to undo this Scale and Bias operation by multiplying by 2 and subtracting 1. Your problem is you don't need to do this when rendering a normal map as you don't really need the original (probably negative) values and render them on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You've left in the `* 2.0 - 1.0` when sampling the normal map.  You probably want to comment that out as well if you're trying to visualize the normal maps for debugging purposes; that way they'll match up with what you see when looking at the normal map in an image viewer.